# Query components and active web front end servers in load balancer

Tags: 2010, search, enterprise-search, query, load-balancing

This Question about the Search

In our SharePoint farm 4 web front end servers and we are using F5 Network Load alancer

- In load balancer we added only one server
- But remaining 3 web servers we have plan to add now
- We created and deployed search service application and search components
- Crawl components created in two separate search app servers
- Only one Query component is created in WFE1 ( this server is in Load balancer)

Question is:

Can i also create more 3 Query components in search service application also?

If i have two web front servers in load balancer and 4 QUery components is all 4  QUery components receive the query request to equally?

If user search for a document is request come to those web front end servers which is not in load balancer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far Search load balancing, SharePoint control it and Most Probably Round Robin.It really does not matter on which server you configured the query component, you can configure it on WFE or on a dedicated server.

So If you have 4 Query Component on 4 wfe and only 2 WFE in LB, even then, SharePoint will route the queries on all 4 component as Round Robin( I believe).

Only thing is to make sure Search is properly configured, and all the search components are healthy & Online.